# How do I remove this space at the bottom of an <a> tag?

Tags: css

I have an `<img>` in an `<a>` and there is a random additional space at the bottom:

```css
a { 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid red; 
}

img {  
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<span><a target="_blank" href="#test"><img border="0" referrerpolicy="origin" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300/E8117F/ffffff" height="300" width="300"></a></span>
```

The link should exactly wrap the image, but there is a white space at the bottom that shouldn't be there:

[image: Get rid of this...]

How do I get rid of this space? I don't want to set `overflow: hidden` or otherwise clip the content - the height and width of the image can change and I want the `<a>` to stretch.

Comment: display: block; or vertical-align: bottom for the img element

Comment: @VXp `display: block` just makes the `<a>` stretch the width, the space is still there at the bottom.

Comment: @Duannx probably - that answer didn't come up when I was searching

Comment: Read again, I wrote for the img element, not the anchor.

Comment: @VXp cheers for the edit, that makes it clearer, if you had put that in an answer you could have had the rep for it.

Comment: Np, maybe some other time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been there, add `display:block` to your `img`

```
img {  
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display:block;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hfpwn2a6/

Answer (score 2):

Set `font-size: 0;` on anchor

Additionally, in case you have to show some text in anchor as well then wrap it in a span and add font size on that span.

```css
a { 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid red; 
   font-size: 0;
}

img {  
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<span><a target="_blank" href="#test"><img border="0" referrerpolicy="origin" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300/E8117F/ffffff" height="300" width="300"></a></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
a { 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid red; 
}

img {  
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; display:block
}
```

```html
<span><a target="_blank" href="#test"><img border="0" referrerpolicy="origin" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300/E8117F/ffffff" height="300" width="300"></a></span>
```

Here I have just added display block to image. Hope it works for you.